# Capitalize lowercase letters in Ruby On Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Does Rails come with some helper method for transforming the first letter of each word to uppercase?

So that

```
"my house is yellow"
```

becomes

```
"My House Is Yellow"
```

Comment: I'm sorry. I find this method here  puts 'one TWO three foUR'.split.map(&:capitalize).join(' ')

Comment: Though it's possible to capitalize every word, that will not necessarily result in a correctly capitalized sentence.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ActiveSupport provides a [titleize](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveSupport/Inflector/titleize) function:

```
'my house is yellow'.titleize
 => "My House Is Yellow"
```

Comment: This is the best answer even though my answer has been accepted. But I would request to un accept my answer and accept this one.

Answer (score 0):

```
1.9.3-p547 :037 > string="my house is yellow"
 => "my house is yellow" 
1.9.3-p547 :038 > string=string.split(' ')
 => ["my", "house", "is", "yellow"] 
1.9.3-p547 :039 > string.each do |a|
1.9.3-p547 :040 >     a.capitalize!
1.9.3-p547 :041?>   end
 => ["My", "House", "Is", "Yellow"] 
1.9.3-p547 :042 > string
 => ["My", "House", "Is", "Yellow"] 
1.9.3-p547 :044 > string.join(' ')
 => "My House Is Yellow" 
1.9.3-p547 :045 >
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no explicit method to do that in one command. But you can try the following the ways.

```
"my house is yellow".gsub(/[A-Za-z']+/,&:capitalize) 
 => "My House Is Yellow"
"my house is yellow".split.map { |i| i.capitalize }.join(' ')
 => "My House Is Yello"
```

Comment: "my house is yellow".gsub(/[A-Za-z']+/,&:capitalize)  I don't understand this

Comment: oh thats the regex pattern way. :)

Answer (score 0):

Just be carful: this is **NOT** Unicode safe method:

```
'привет, мир!'.titleize
"привет, мир!"
```

In order to be Unicode safe please take a look on [unicode](https://rubygems.org/gems/unicode) gem.

```
Unicode.capitalize('привет, мир!')
"Привет, мир!"
```

This gem correctly handles Unicode character, however it doesn't have `titleize` method, it has only `capitalize` method.